# Does water get displaced by itself when being filled in a glass or does it "pile up" like a denser substance?

Tags: forces, water, displacement

**Disclaimer:** *I do not have a very strong background in physics so if this is too elementary I apologize*

## The Question:

When water is being poured into a glass, is the stationary water (i.e. that which is already in the glass) displaced by the water being pored?

(*Visualization*)

[image]

If so, is the "more recently" pored water closer to the bottom of this cup (or vise versa) ? Would the answer to this rule hold true with a larger vessel?

Hope to see some answers!

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point to the question. Water is water, there's no discernible difference between water and water. Water added to a container already containing water just becomes more water, unless you're talking about water containing regular hydrogen and another containing, say, deuterium or tritium, but that's not what you asked. In the animation, there's enough mixing going on that there is no stratification.

Comment: @BillOertell I'm curious about how it happens.

Comment: Try filling a glass halfway up, then add food coloring to the remainder of your water reservoir, and continue filling. Now you can see exactly where the new water goes relative to the old water.

Comment: Yes there is displacement. If the one poured touch the bottom is matter of the speed is coming down and/or the height of the water already present. Do what The Photon suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Both masses of water mix.

- If poured more energetically, as in the gif visualization, the mixing will happen mostly in the form [turbulent diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulent_diffusion).
- If poured with extreme care, with small amounts of water added with close to no speed (such as from an eyedropper close to the water surface), then the main mixing mechanism will be [molecular diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_diffusion).